# How many countries in each continent?

Tags: geography, enigmatic-puzzle

In [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states) of the world's sovereign states, exactly sixteen of the UN member states and observer states have a certain property P, and so does the disputed territory of Abkhazia.

- Exactly 2 of these countries are in South America.
- Exactly 5 are in Africa.
- Exactly 4 (not counting Abkhazia) used to be in the USSR.

This should be enough to ensure the puzzle has a unique solution; I can add more clues if necessary.

**What is the property P? Which are the sixteen countries?**

Comment: 4 downvotes? Really? I wish I knew what was wrong with this puzzle, so that I can improve next time.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the people down-voting the question felt like this was too broad. It also kinda feels like a "guess what I'm thinking" question.

Comment: Too broad ... and yet nobody has come up with a possibility that fits all the information and *isn't* the intended answer. "Guess what I'm thinking" questions are often more or less undoable without loads of hints, but TNLenny got the correct answer within half an hour!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Contain the letter Z (in the English spelling)

Azerbaijan · Belize · Bosnia and Herzegovina · Brazil · Czech Republic · Kazakhstan · Kyrgyzstan · Mozambique · New Zealand· Swaziland · Switzerland · Tanzania · Uzbekistan · Venezuela · Zambia · Zimbabwe

Comment: Yes, but the OP said that Abkhazia doesn't count, which does have the letter Z

Comment: I read it as "Exactly 16 States AND Abkhazia" have the Property - then this would match! Or the Question has to be reformulated if it means "16 States of the Group (UN+Abkhazia)" have Property P

Comment: @PythonMaster and Falco - I've edited the question to make this issue clear.

Comment: Well done TNLenny! How did you get this so fast?

Comment: I looked for commonalities. Started down a rabbit hole of 8 letter countries, but former SSRS didn't match that (there are exactly two 8 letter countries in SA).

Comment: I looked for commonalities. With such a wide variety of countries I figured it had to be something pretty specific and not geo-political. 

Started down a rabbit hole of 8 letter countries, but former SSRS didn't match that (there are exactly two 8 letter countries in SA).

Then thought, hmmm. Z is an uncommon letter. Let's see.... Brazil, Venezuela. Yup. Kazakh, uzbek, azerbaijan, Kyrgyzstan, yup. Africa? Yup. Was fun!

Comment: I could see where the Abkhazia conditions could be confusing, but I read the intention as 16 UN states plus Abkhazia (obv) and 4 former SSRs "not counting" abkhazia meaning "other than"/plus.